# Find the coordinates of the third vertex of a right triangle programmatically

Tags: java, trigonometry

Been stuck on this for awhile even though there's probably an easy solution.

Given two points:

P1 = (5,5) and P2 = (6,10) 
The distance between these two points D = 5.1

Is it possible to find the coordinates of where the third vertex would need to go to make an isosceles right triangle with either point?

[image]

Anyone able to help?

Is this right?

```
    double ax = 5;
    double ay = 5;
    double bx = 6;
    double by = 10;

    // Vector of A > B
    double abx = bx - ax;
    double aby = by - ay;

    // Rotate 90 degrees to get Vector B > C
    double n = Math.toRadians(90.0);       
    double rx = (abx * Math.cos(n)) - (aby * Math.sin(n));
    double ry = (abx * Math.sin(n)) + (aby * Math.cos(n));

    // Point B + Vector B > C
    double cx = bx + rx;
    double cy = by + ry;
```

Ending with P3 = (1, 11)

[image]

Comment: Yes, there is. Keep in mind that there are 6 possible solutions for a valid third point if you want to make an isosceles right triangle with two existing points.

Comment: Try it on paper then translate to code.

Comment: Able to show me how?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better suited for [math.se].

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint:

[image]

As [@f1sh said](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214525/f1sh), there are 6 points (in red). In the image, I've rotated your line for easier representation, so you can rotate it back and see what results you should be getting.

Comment: Think I got it, could you take a look at my answer ?

Comment: @NemoNobody Looks good for finding one of the points. You should post it as an answer instead of an edit to the question. This will allow peer reviews.